# Bring in .xib only in detail view in master view design

Tags: ios, objective-c, master-detail

I've looked at a few examples but I haven't been able to get things to work properly yet. I am in a large code base that is a universal app. I am bringing in a .xib like so:

```
TestView *newView =
[[TestView alloc] init];

[self presentViewController:newView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

That loads the .xib just fine on the iPhone side of things, but in the iPad sim the .xib covers the whole screen. How can I make it to only cover the details view? I understand that in the appdelegate it makes two view controllers (i.e. the splitviewcontroller) but I have no option to do something like

```
[detailViewController presentViewController:newView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create an instance of a UISplitViewController in the AppDelegate. The UISplitViewController is only availabe on the iPad, so you have to enclose this in an if-statement

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    UIViewController *master = [self buildMaster];
    UIViewController *detail = [self buildDetail];
    UISplitViewController *splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
    splitViewController.viewControllers = @[master, detail];
    [self.window setRootViewController:splitViewController];
}
```